# My ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: docker, server, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

When I write docker-compose up on server, it gives me an error above.

I searched some solved this problem by writing `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

It gives me this error  `usermod: group 'docker' does not exist`

and did   **export DOCKER_HOST=localhost:port**

But it gave me again `: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at  http://localhost:1774`

Comment: Try running dockerd or sudo dockerd if required first to start daemon. If you start dockerd with sudo you may want to run docker-compose up with sudo also. otherwise it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the docker daemon if it is not running. Add "sudo" in the below command, if it is needed.

```
service docker restart
```

I found the related issue here https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181